# Binding a collection to a list box

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have an object called TheObject. 
Each 'TheObject' contains attribute A,B, and C.

I also have a collection of 'TheObject's
 ObservalbeCollection TheCollection

I want to bind this collection to a ListView 
so that it displays Coloum A, Column B, Column C across the screen.

So the list would resemble :

TheCollection[1].A          TheCollection[1].B          TheCollection[1].C

TheCollection[2].A          TheCollection[2].B          TheCollection[2].C
etc.

what is the simplest way to bind the listview???

Thank you very,much

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding C}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[[Binding basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)]